# Rownum not woking in found highest salary

Tags: oracle

select * from (select * from (select emp_salary from employee order by emp_salary) where rownum<6 order by emp_salary)where rownum =6;

in above query rownum is not working , if i will run below query then rownum is working, i am confussed about it please help

select * from (select * from (select emp_salary from employee order by emp_salary) where rownum<6 order by emp_salary)where rownum =1;

select * from (select * from (select emp_salary from employee order by emp_salary) where rownum<6 order by emp_salary)where rownum =1;

Comment: Rownum is the row ordinal for every row returned to the consumer. It cannot skip value 1 by definition

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with:

```
  select * 
   from (
         select rownum as num_row, x.* 
           from (
                 select emp_salary 
                   from employee 
                  order by emp_salary
                ) x
          where rownum <= 6 
          order by emp_salary
        ) 
  where num_row = 6;
```

Thanks.